# How to manually set navigation state in @react-navigation/native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a case where we allow users to complete a multi-step form without logging in. When they complete the last step and hit submit, we ask them to log in.
That's when I save the navigation state in the async storage. After a successful login, when the user opens the app again I want to be able to load the saved state into the current navigation state.
Meaning that they would be at the last step of the multi-step form and also be able to go back to the previous step.

What I have tried:

1. Navigating directly to the last step, but this case isn't optimal because when the user goes back, he will go to the home screen and not the previous step.
2. [Persisting react-navigation state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/), I debugged and saw that I get the correct data from the async storage, I've set it into the initialState of the navigation provider, but nothing really happens. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in this step. Should the react-navigation navigate to the last step? I have seen the index saved from the async storage navigation and it's the correct one.
3. I've also tried `navigation.reset`('navigationFromAsyncStorage') to no avail.

The structure of my navigators is like this:

```
const RootStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
       //MultiStepForm is also Stack.Navigator
      <Stack.Screen
        name={NavigatorRoute.MULTI_STEP_FORM}
        component={MultiStepForm}
      />
     ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Edit: Additional info**
I managed to load back the multi step form data from the async storage. But what I am also and more importantly trying to do is also load the routes back into the navigation stack. So if my multi step form is 5 screens long,on app load I want to go to the last step and also have previous 4 screens loaded into the stack. So if user goes back, he goes back to the previous screen.

Comment: Have you tried using the useFocusEffect hook? You can try and use the hook to detect if there is any data in the async storage and load back the form data whenever the mutiform screen is back in focus.

Comment: I managed to load back the multi step form data from the async storage. But what I am also and more importantly trying to do is also load the routes back into the navigation stack. So if my multi step form is 5 screens long, I want to be able to go to the last step and also have previous 4 screens loaded into the stack. So if user goes back, he goes back to the previous screen. Hope I was clear enough, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

what if just reset the routes in the fist screen of the app (like splash screen)

```
  let storageRoutes;
  navigation.dispatch((state) => {
    return CommonActions.reset({
      ...state,
      routes: storageRoutes,
      index: storageRoutes.length - 1,
    });
  });
```